# If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$, how to find $f^{(36)} (0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, summation

> If $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$, find $f^{(36)} (0)$.

So far I have tried letting $a=x^2+x+1$ and then finding the first several derivatives to see if some terms would disappear because the third derivative of $a$ is $0$, but the derivatives keep getting longer and longer. Am I on the right track? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Complete the square - some stuff cleans up.

Comment: You can try other way round think in an infinite series, and its nth derivative and its setting it to zero gives you coefficient in series, so this just become a power series question..

Comment: @ Sean Roberson How would I "complete the square"?

Comment: May I ask why anyone would care about anything past the fifth derivative, or past the second or third if it's not physics-related?

Comment: @DonielF: you can ask why, but that's the difference between scientists/engineers and mathematicians...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

We can write:

$$1+ x + x^2 = \frac{1-x^3}{1-x}$$

Therefore:

$$f(x) = \frac{1-x}{1-x^3} $$

We can then expand this in powers of $x$:

$$f(x) = (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{3 k}$$

which is valid for $\left|x\right|<1$. The coefficient of $x^{36}$ is thus equal to $1$, so the 36th derivative at $x = 0$ is $36!$ .

Comment: By far the best answer.

Comment: How did you get from $f(x) = \frac{1-x}{1-x^3}$ to $f(x) = (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{3 k}$?

Comment: @chrismc You apply the formula for the geometric series to $$\frac{1}{1-x^3}$$ where instead of $x$ you have $x^3$, that's why you get $\left(x^3\right)^k = x^{3k}$ in the sumand.

Comment: What if $|x| \ge 1$?

Comment: @AHB This is beside the point, since we only care about small $x$. The reason we can do so is the uniqueness of Maclaurin (or Taylor) expansion around a particular point.

Comment: @AHB - it's the radius of convergence if you're interested in further reading.  This particular Maclaurin series will not converge by adding more terms if $|x| > 1$ because $x$ represents the ratio in the geometric series. So if you have an infinite series with terms $a_n=x^n$ and the ratio, $x$, is 2, starting at $n=0$, for example, you'd be adding up the infinite sum 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32, etc... which diverges to infinity. For any value of $|x|≥1$.

Answer (score 16):

Let $\omega$ be a complex cube root of $1$. Then Partial Fraction representation of $f(x)$ is given by

$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2+x+1} = \dfrac{1}{(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)} = \dfrac{1}{\omega - \omega^2}\Big(\dfrac{1}{x-\omega} - \dfrac{1}{x - \omega^2}\Big)$.

Find successive derivatives to show that

$f^{(36)}(x) = \dfrac{1}{\omega - \omega^2}(36! (x-\omega)^{-37} - 36! (x - \omega^2)^{-37})$.

Let $x = 0$ and use $\omega^3 = 1$.

Comment: What? Is this jokingly supposed to be hard to understand, like an obfuscated C contest but for math?

Comment: Been a while since I've done partial fractions, but ${(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)} = {x^2+x+1}$?  Would've though the middle terms signs don't work, as they'd be negative

Comment: @JeopardyTempest $(x-\omega)(x - \omega^2) = x^2 - (\omega + \omega^2) x + \omega^3 = x^2 - (-1) x + 1 = x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: Indeed, yep, got it, my mistake... I thought you'd later said omega = 1, not omega^3 = 1.  Whoops

Answer (score 14):

Use $$x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)$$

By this hint we obtain:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\right)^{(36)}_{x=0}=\left(\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)}\right)^{(36)}_{x=0}=$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt3i}\left(\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i}-\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i}\right)\right)^{(36)}_{x=0}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt3i}\left(\frac{36!}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{37}}-\frac{36!}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{37}}\right)_{x=0}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt3i}\left(\frac{36!}{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{37}}-\frac{36!}{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i\right)^{37}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt3i}\left(\frac{36!}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i}-\frac{36!}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i}\right)=36!$$

Answer (score 10):

Hint 1: Can you write your function as a sum of powers of $x$? If so, that's a Maclaurin series, and finding the 36th derivative (at $0$) from that should be pretty easy.

Hint 2: What's a series expression for $\frac{1}{1+y}$ (at least when $y$ is small)?

Hint 3: Have you heard of "completing the square"?

Comment: Hint 2 basically leads to my answer. Which doesn't look particularly clean, though.

Comment: Yeah...that's why I put in hint 3, which makes it much nicer.

Answer (score 5):

Do you know a smooth function can be expressed uniquely in a Taylor series around a point? Therefore $f(x)$ can be expressed *uniquely* around zero as 
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{36}\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(0)x^n+o(x^{36}).$$

We also note that when $x$ is small, we have that 
$$\frac1{1+(x+x^2)}=\sum_{m=0}^{36}(-1)^m(x+x^2)^m+o(x^{36})$$
according to geometric series expansion.

Then we have to pick out all the  $x^{36}$ terms and sum their coefficients up. Still a tedious task because we have to look from $m=18$ all the way to $m=36$. But the complexity might be smaller than directly computing the derivatives.

Edit: not particularly tedious. Since for each $m$ in question $(x+x^2)^m$ has only one $x^{36}$ term. For $m=18$ it is $(-1)^{18}=1$, obviously. For $m=19$ it is $(-1)^{19}{19\choose 2}=-{19\choose 2}$. For $m=20$ it is $(-1)^{20}{20\choose 4}$ and so on. There is clearly a pattern in it.

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit of the summation be infinity since your are writing a taylor series for the function?

Comment: @chrismc alright, maybe a more proper terminology is Maclaurin series.

Comment: So would the upper limit of the summation be or not be infinity? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @chrismc in the context of Taylor expansion or Maclaurin series or whatever is the terminology, the upper limit is finite. In the context of power series it should be infinite. They are very different concepts.

Comment: Oh ok sorry. What does the o mean?

Comment: @chrismc please google "little-o notation".

Answer (score 1):

A non power/taylor series method using Leibniz' generalize product rule:

$$ (fg)^{n}(x) = \sum_{r = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} f^{n-r}(x) g^{r}(x)$$

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + x + 1}$ and $g(x) = x^2 + x +1 $

Then $f(x) g(x) = 1$. We apply the rule to $fg$.

If $a_k = f^{k}(0)$ the we get the recurrence relation

$$a_k + ka_{k-1} + k(k-1)a_{k-2} = 0$$

With $a_{0} = 1$ and $a_1 = -1$

Now let $b_k = \dfrac{a_k}{k!}$, then we get

$$b_k + b_{k-1} + b_{k-2} = 0$$

with $b_{0} = 1$ and $b_{1} = -1$.
Thus we get that the $b_i$ are

$$1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, \dots$$

We see that $b_{3k} = 1$, $b_{3k+1} = -1$ and $b_{3k+2} = 0$.

Thus $$a_{36} = b_{36}\cdot 36! = 36!$$